# How can I add non-overlapping labels for North-Eastern US states in proc gmap?

Tags: sas, label

I am trying to plot two variables on US map. I would like to show price of product A and the difference v/s product B below it inside parenthesis. The code is almost finished. Only problem I am facing is that I am unable to put labels for smaller north eastern states like New Jersey, vermont and Hampshire without them overlapping. I would like something like the attached file wherein the above mentioned states' labels  are shown with a line.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
proc import datafile="../Book8.csv" out=response dbms=csv replace;
run;

proc export data=response outfile="check.csv" dbms=csv replace;
run;

proc sort data=response out=sallx2(drop=Price_B); by STATECODE; run;
proc sort data=maps.us2 out=sus2(keep=STATE STATECODE); by STATECODE; run;

data mapfips;
merge sallx2 (in=a)
sus2 (in=b)
;
by STATECODE;
if a;
run;

data mapfips;
set mapfips;
dummy="$";
dummy1="(";
dummy2=")";
new_Price_A=catx("", of dummy Price_A);
new_Difference=catx("", of dummy1 dummy Difference dummy2);
run;


proc sort data=mapfips out=smapfips; by STATE; run;
proc sort data=maps.uscenter out=suscenter(keep=STATE X Y) nodupkey;
by STATE; run;
data mapfips2;
merge smapfips (in=a)
suscenter (in=b)
;
by STATE;
if a;
run;

data stlabel;
length function $ 8 position $ 1
text $ 20 style $ 30;
set mapfips2;
retain flag 0
xsys ysys '2'
hsys '3' when 'a';
format Difference dollar5.2;
text=new_Difference; style="'Albany AMT'";
color='black'; size=2; position='7'; output;
format Price_A dollar5.2;
text=new_Price_A; style="'Albany AMT'";
color='black'; size=2; position='4'; output;
if ocean='Y' then do;
text=new_Difference; position='6'; output;
function='move';
flag=1;
end;
else if flag=1 then do;
function='draw'; size=2; output;
flag=0; 
end;
output; 
run;

proc contents data=stlabel; 
run;

proc format;
picture Difference_
low - -0.01  = 'negative'
0.00 = 'parity'
0.01 -high = 'positive'
;    
run;

proc contents data=response;

pattern1 color=green;
pattern2 color=yellow;
pattern3 color= red;


title 'PRODUCT A V/S PRODUCT B';


proc gmap
data=response
map=maps.us
all;
id STATECODE;
format Difference Difference_.;
choro Difference / discrete annotate=stlabel ;
run;
quit;
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you already have customized the annotation position based on maps.uscenter:ocean.  You can further customize the annotation based on specific states.  Set the special states x, and y and create some more annotation rows for functions move/draw or use %line from annotation macros setup by `%ANNOMAC`

Comment: Hey Richard,Thanks for the answer. I am new to proc gmap and used some online resources to reach up to this point. The lines starting from if ocean="Y" are not really helping and I am still getting a map wherein numbers are overlapping. If you could help me with the code that can plot labels outside the state for Vermont, new hampshire and new jersey, then that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pawan:

You need to understand "Annotation Variables" and "Annotation Functions", as well as Maps.USCENTER

This code is a modification of the SAS sample "Example 6: Labeling the States on a U.S. Map".  The code is more verbose than the example, for explanation, and due to two label lines per state and call-out tweaking.

The USCENTER data has a special feature:

- `Ocean` variable, when `Y` (yes) there will be two rows for a state

  - First row is 'safe` X & Y for text, **offset** from the states actual geo-center. Use for placing labels and start-point for call-out line.
  - Second row is X & Y for actual geo-center and end-point for call-out line.

The code has features

- `Flag` variable, retained to track if row is the subsequent row of an ocean state call out line, and thus the function should be set to `'draw'`
- Tweaks for specific states to change SAS provided call-out coordinates
  `if state2 = 'VT' then do;
         * tweak first end-point of call out for VT;
         x = 0.27;
         y = 0.20;
         position1 = 'A'; /* RAD: right aligned 1/2 cell above **/
         position2 = 'D'; /* RAD: right aligned 1/2 cell below **/
  end;`

The code does not create new call-outs where none existed before. *You would have to add rows to a copy of maps.uscenters data to create a new call-outs.*

```
/* Original from SAS Example 6: Labeling the States on a U.S. Map */

goptions reset=global gunit=pct border cback=white
         colors=(black blue green red)
         ftext='Albany AMT'  /* RAD: Change default font to 'Albany AMT' */
         htitle=6 htext=3
;

data WORK.myTexts;
  set maps.uscenter;
  by state;
  if first.state;
  line1 = 'Line 1';
  line2 = 'Line 2';

  state2 = fipstate(state);
  if state2 ne 'DC';
run;

data WORK.map_annotation; /* RAD: use WORK libref instead of REFLIB */
   length function $ 8 x y 8 position $1 text $20;
   retain 
    flag 0 
    xsys ysys '2' /* RAD: coordinate system for drawing, 2 means data values */
    hsys '3'  /* RAD: coordinate system for heights, 3 means % of graphics output area */
    when 'a'  /* RAD: annotation occurs after all procedure drawing is done */
    style "'Albany AMT'"  /* RAD: quoted style value indicates a true type font is being requested for drawn labels */
   ;
   merge
      myTexts (in=myAnno)
      maps.uscenter (drop=long lat)
  ;

  by state;
  if myAnno;

   function='label';
   size=1.5; /* RAD: size for label is font height in HSYS coordinate system, make it small enough for stacking two labels */
   position='B'; /* RAD: text position is centered about X and Y at half cell above Y */

   if ocean='Y' then do;

         position1 = 'C'; /* RAD: left aligned 1/2 cell above */
         position2 = 'F'; /* RAD: left aligned 1/2 cell below */

         if state2 = 'VT' then do;
           * tweak first end-point of call out for VT;
           x = 0.27;
           y = 0.20;
           position1 = 'A'; /* RAD: right aligned 1/2 cell above */
           position2 = 'D'; /* RAD: right aligned 1/2 cell below */
         end;

         text=catx(':', state2, line1); 
         position=position1;
         output;

         text=line2;
         position=position2;  
         output;

         function='move'; /* RAD: move the pen to the start of call-out line */
         flag=1;
         output;
   end;
   else if flag=1 then do;
         /* Dealing with an Ocean state,
          * this is the second observation for it (data feature of MAPS.USCENTER) 
          */
         function='draw'; /* RAD: draw line to the end of the call-out line (which is state geo-center) */
         size=.25; /* Size for 'draw' is line thickness */
         flag=0;
         output;
   end;
   else do;
         /* USCENTER row is neither ocean state, nor ocean state 2nd row */
         /* Thus a state is one without a call-out line
          * place the annotation at the states center */
         text=line1;
         position='B';  /* RAD: Center aligned 1/2 cell above */
         output;
         text=line2;
         position='E';  /* RAD: Center aligned 1/2 cell above */
         output;
   end;
run;

title 'Positioning State Labels with MAPS.USCENTER';
footnote j=r 'GR19N06 ';

pattern1 value=mempty color=blue repeat=50;

proc gmap data=maps.us map=maps.us;
   id state;
   choro state / nolegend
                 annotate=WORK.map_annotation;
run;
quit;
```